# xml simplexml_load_file not parsing special or other language characters

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

I am using below google suggestion query and it return xml format output, in this output it contains special or other language characters.

```
http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?output=toolbar&hl=en&q=facebook+e
```

It gives below xml format output...

```
<toplevel>
<CompleteSuggestion>
<suggestion data="facebook en español"/>
</CompleteSuggestion>
<CompleteSuggestion>
<suggestion data="facebook emojis"/>
</CompleteSuggestion>
<CompleteSuggestion>
<suggestion data="facebook event photo size"/>
</CompleteSuggestion>
<CompleteSuggestion>
<suggestion data="facebook emoticons"/>
</CompleteSuggestion>
<CompleteSuggestion>
<suggestion data="facebook email"/>
</CompleteSuggestion>
<CompleteSuggestion>
<suggestion data="facebook events"/>
</CompleteSuggestion>
<CompleteSuggestion>
<suggestion data="facebook earnings"/>
</CompleteSuggestion>
<CompleteSuggestion>
<suggestion data="facebook earnings date"/>
</CompleteSuggestion>
<CompleteSuggestion>
<suggestion data="facebook email address"/>
</CompleteSuggestion>
<CompleteSuggestion>
<suggestion data="facebook event banner size"/>
</CompleteSuggestion>
</toplevel>
```

When I use below code to load this xml file foreach I am getting error ...

```
foreach ($xml->children() as $child) {
foreach ($child->suggestion->attributes() as $dta) {
echo "<br>";
echo $dta;
}
}
```

output is getting below error message...

```
Warning: simplexml_load_file():
http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?
output=toolbar&hl=en&q=facebook.'%20'.e:1: parser error : Input is not  
proper UTF-8, indicate encoding ! Bytes: 0xF1 0x6F 0x6C 0x22 in 

Warning: simplexml_load_file(): es"/></CompleteSuggestion>
<CompleteSuggestion><suggestion data="facebook en espa in
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should encode in `UTF-8` the response of google suggestion query before trying to parse it.

```
$encodedResponse = utf8_encode(file_get_contents('http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?output=toolbar&hl=en&q=facebook+e'));
$xml = simplexml_load_string($encodedResponse);
```